# SImple Android TCP Client timeout

Tags: java, android, tcp

Hello: I am writing a  simple android TCP Client to be used with an Inventek Embedded TCP server (with DHCP). This client sends a short message, a number of times, and stops.

I am able to find and get the  DHCP address assigned from the server network (the server debug shows this). The  embedded Inventek server works with the 'TCP Telnet Terminal' app.

Note, My Android phone shows a exclamation point next to the WiFi network Icon, yet shows it connected and I don't think this is the problem, as I do receive a DHCP address.

When I run my code I receive the following.
 ~~ SocketTimeoutException in the android debug. and the following:

This is the debug:

```
  08-16 17:07:46.614 14378-14426/? W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.10.1 (port 5024) after 1000ms
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
    at com.example.tony.escomms.ClientLoop.run(TcpClient.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The code:

```
package com.example.tony.escomms;


import android.util.Log;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.net.Socket;

public class TcpClient {


    private static String LOG_TAG = "TcpClient";

    public TcpClient() {

        ClientLoop cl = new ClientLoop("Hi");
    }
}

class ClientLoop implements Runnable {


    private static String LOG_TAG = "ClientLoop";
    String message;
    public ClientLoop(String message) {

        this.message = message;
        try {
            new Thread(this).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Error: Calling Task");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Connecting...");
        try {

            Socket socket = new Socket();
            if (socket == null){
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "socket is null");
                return;
            }

            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.10.1", 5024), 1000);
            DataOutputStream toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            if (toServer == null) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "data stream  is null");
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                toServer.writeBytes(message + 'n');
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Sending " + message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Error: Comm fault ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you manage to connect using regular telnet from your computer? it seems to be just a conectivity problem nothing related to android sdk

Comment: @AlessandroOliveira. Yes I can telnet to it from a Linux computer.